# Promote the Orthogonality between Rows of Matrix $ S $

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we want to solve the following optimization problem in $S \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times T}$, where $T \gg S$,

$$\min_{S} f(S) \mbox{ subject to } SS^T \mbox{is diagonal}$$

which means rows of the matrix $S$ are mutually orthogonal.

I am suggested to solve this alternative problem by the following method:

$$\min_{S} f(S) + \|\mathcal{P}(SS^T)\|_1$$

in which $\mathcal{P}$ is a projection onto the off-diagonal indexes.

But I don't this $\ell_1$ penalty will promote the orthogonality between each rows by simply promote the sparsity of the off-diagonal elements, since we are not doing any actions like block coordinate descent to promote the orthogonality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you know about $f$? Why not introduce $n (n-1)$ quadratic equality constraints?

Comment: I think you should just rephrase the question into something like "Orthogonal Projection onto Semi Orthogonal Matrix Space". This way you'll get answers.